# Data Annotations - Range attribute with long type

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, data-annotations, dynamic-data

I have an ASP.NET Dynamic Data Web Site

I'm scaffolding the model to apply validation

I have some `bigint` fields and I'm suing SQL Server 2008

My context represents correctly my `bigint` fields using `long` types:

```
public System.Nullable<long> ProcessorAffinityMask64Bit
```

I try to apply validation as follows:

```
[Range(typeof(long), "0", "4294967295")]
public object ProcessorAffinityMask { get; set; }
```

I have also tried:

```
[Range(0, 4294967295)]
public object ProcessorAffinityMask { get; set; }
```

And

```
[Range(0D, 4294967295D)]
public object ProcessorAffinityMask { get; set; }
```

But in any case I receive the following error:

> > Value was either too large or too small for an Int32.

[image]

**So How can I validate a long field?**

Comment: Try implement a new `ValidationAttribute`. If you decompile the `RangeAttribute` class you will find that there is a `Convert.ToInt32()` in the code.

Comment: Don't you have to set your property to `long` instead of `object`?

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar issue in our project and we ended up removing the RangeValidator from the Integer_Edit control.

The RangeAttribute you're adding to the metadata then does the heavy lifting, as intended.

The other option is to create new FieldTemplates and use a UIHintAttribute to point toward those, instead.